# Two identical $regex declarations behave differently in Mongo shell

Tags: regex, mongodb

According to [$regex documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/), the following $regex declarations are identical:

```
{ <field>: { $regex: /pattern/, $options: '<options>' } }
{ <field>: { $regex: 'pattern', $options: '<options>' } }
{ <field>: { $regex: /pattern/<options> } }
```

I was playing around with the [zips.json dataset](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/) in the Mongo shell, and tried to find cities that begin and end with the same character. However, the query returned different results depending on whether I used `'pattern'` or `/pattern/`.

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.1
connecting to: test
> db.version()
3.0.1
> db.zips.find( { city: { $regex: '^(.).*\1$' } }, { city: true } ).count()
0
> db.zips.find( { city: { $regex: /^(.).*\1$/ } }, { city: true } ).count()
1418
```

Is there any difference in behavior despite what the documentation says? Something to do with the latter being a JavaScript regex perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. In the first declaration, I should have escaped the backslash like this:

```
db.zips.find( { city: { $regex: '^(.).*\\1$' } }, { city: true } ).count()
```

Comment: You can delete the question :)